# How to deal with a specific type of expection

Tags: java

```
class A{
    public static void main(String[]args){
         int = 0;
         try{
         i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         }
        catch()
        System.out.println("this value of i is" + i);
}
```

How can I print exception using toString if a exception occurs. I am assuming of only one command line argument here.

Comment: syntax error in your code ..catch(Exception e) { //Statement }  sys out;

Comment: Huh?  You can catch the base "Execption" type.  What are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), you will find that it throws `NumberFormatException`:

> **Throws:**
>   [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

Hence, that is the exception you will want to catch:

```
try{
    i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // handle exception
}
```

If you want to print out this exception if it is encountered, you could use `nfe.printStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the catch portion has the exception as a parameter. It's illustrated atop this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html